# Grunt Copy dont when including multi dot in file names

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy, backbone-paginator

While working on **grunt-contrib-copy**, i have a problem with multi-dot filled file names.

For Example: **backbone.paginator.js**

in my Gruntfile.coffee i defined variables;

```
backbonepaginator   = 'public/vendors/backbone.paginator.js' : '/bower/backbone.paginator/dist/backbone.paginator.js'
```

this doesnt copy to destination folder;

```
    copy:
        main:
            files: [
                expand: true
                cwd: 'src/css/'
                src: ['**/*.css']
                dest: 'public/css/'
                ext: '.css'
            ,
                expand: true
                cwd: 'src/js/'
                src: ['**/*.js']
                dest: 'public/js/'
                ext: '.js'
            ,
                backbone,
                underscore,
                backbonepaginator
            ]
```

Without any error and corrupt, other files are copying but backbonepaginator doesnt.

I am using Windows 8 and think so the problem are multi dots in file names.
Because when i remove or change the file name in bower directory, it copies succesfully.

Thanks for your helps.

**SOLVED:**

I found my problem was '/' before "bower".

I changed;

```
backbonepaginator   = 'public/vendors/backbone.paginator.js' : '/bower/backbone.paginator/dist/backbone.paginator.js'
```

**as**

```
backbonepaginator   = 'public/vendors/backbone.paginator.js' : 'bower/backbone.paginator/dist/backbone.paginator.js'
```

Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried having the Gruntfile in `js` format? I would try that, just to make sure that the `coffeescript` abstraction has nothing to do with the error. That and I don't think you need the `, **/*.*.js`, because that pattern is already covered by the preceding one (try removing that first, then replacing coffee with plain js).

Comment: ah so! i forgot while trying do it ,'**/*.*.js' and now i fixed again in my question, but the problem was before it.